# Laravel Eloquent ORM , One to Many , Many to many?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

So I have this DB structure:

PAGES

```
id - integer
name - string
```

ROWS

```
id - integer
page_id - integer
name - string
```

COMPONENTS

```
id - integer
row_id - integer
name - string
```

PAGES has many ROWS and each ROWS has many COMPONENTS

My Page model has:

```
public function rows() {
    return $this->hasMany('Models\Rows');
}
```

My Rows model has

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Models\Page');
}  


public function components() {
    return $this->hasMany('Models\Components');
}
```

And my Components model has

```
public function rows()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Models\Rows');
}
```

So at this moment I have 2 step method to get all the components in a page/row.

First I find the rows :

```
$rows   = PageModel::find(2)->rows;
```

then loop through $rows and find the components.

But isn't a way to do this more efficient?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Thnx! In the end somebody on the Laravel forum gave a more detailed answer .. but still the same direction : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/one-to-many-many-to-many

Answer (score -1):

You need a hasManyThrough relationship. Its very basic for your case. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)